# Innobackupex hot backup not working with MDB

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, replication, mariadb, innobackupex

```
140308 17:15:43 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see 

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 5.5.36-MariaDB-1~precise-log
key_buffer_size=67108864
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=1002
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 2263780 K bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2b)[0x7f230db5f37b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x471)[0x7f230d785ca1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfcb0)[0x7f230c617cb0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7f230b63e425]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x17b)[0x7f230b641b8b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x70cc4d)[0x7f230d9c4c4d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x711cd3)[0x7f230d9c9cd3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x69b8cf)[0x7f230d9538cf]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6d7e41)[0x7f230d98fe41]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6d8b98)[0x7f230d990b98]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6727bc)[0x7f230d92a7bc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x62ccb0)[0x7f230d8e4cb0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_in t+0x48)[0x7f230d788bc8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x39722b)[0x7f230d64f22b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x689)[0x7f230d651839]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x3035a9)[0x7f230d5bb5a9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x514)[0x7f230d5c0774]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7f230b62976d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2fe6e9)[0x7f230d5b66e9]
The manual page at  contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
140308 17:15:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Hi All,
I created my backup:
innobackupex --defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --host=localhost --password= --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /mnt/tempbackup/

rsynced to the replication box:
rsync -avz --progress

restoring:
innobackupex --copy-back /mnt/tempdisk/

innobackupex: Starting to copy InnoDB system tablespace
innobackupex: in '/mnt/tempdisk'
innobackupex: back to original InnoDB data directory '/var/lib/mysql'
innobackupex: Copying '/mnt/tempdisk/ibdata1' to '/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1'

innobackupex: Starting to copy InnoDB undo tablespaces
innobackupex: in '/mnt/tempdisk'
innobackupex: back to '/var/lib/mysql'

innobackupex: Starting to copy InnoDB log files
innobackupex: in '/mnt/tempdisk'
innobackupex: back to original InnoDB log directory '/var/lib/mysql'
innobackupex: Finished copying back files.

140308 17:47:40 innobackupex: completed OK!

chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql

Master box:
innobackupex --version
InnoDB Backup Utility v1.5.1-xtrabackup; Copyright 2003, 2009 Innobase Oy

mysql --version
mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Slave box:
innobackupex --version
InnoDB Backup Utility v1.5.1-xtrabackup; Copyright 2003, 2009 Innobase Oy

mysql --version
mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.36-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Did I miss something?

Regards,
Andrew

Comment: Even though MariaDB should just work with the same files, I would still take a dump with `mysqldump` for transferring it to MariaDB.  That will work and it will also rebuild the tables while creating them which will reclaim space in the InnoDB data files.

Comment: I used xtrabackup because I can use it to build a replication for my db. My 2 other DB just worked fine with xtrabackup, 3rd not. I try to use mysqldump --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --flush-logs --hex-blob --master-data=2 -A but it also not working for me. My binlog-format is ROW.